# XAML UI Button. Resizible image and Text

Tags: xaml

I have tried to create a xaml UI layout that has buttons, at the moment TILEs. They should have image and text, and both of them should resize according the screen size.

How would you add resizable text/header/title to this?
Thank you for in advance.

```
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" x:Name="MenuGrid" UseLayoutRounding="True" Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*" MaxHeight="150"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*" MinHeight="75" />
            <RowDefinition Height="3*" MinHeight="75" />
            <RowDefinition Height="3*" MinHeight="75" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Source="/Resources/logo.png" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" StretchDirection="DownOnly"/>

        <controls:Tile Name="tileInvoice" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" ToolTip="Invoice">
            <controls:Tile.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="/Resources/invoice.png"/>
            </controls:Tile.Background>
        </controls:Tile>
        <controls:Tile Name="tileCustomer" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <controls:Tile.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="/Resources/customer.png" />
            </controls:Tile.Background>
        </controls:Tile>
        <controls:Tile Name="tileItem" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <controls:Tile.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="/Resources/item.png"/>
            </controls:Tile.Background>
        </controls:Tile>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not `MahApps` specific, it's about xaml layout. If you want scalable controls wrap them in a `Viewbox`

```
<Viewbox>
    <controls:Tile Name="tileInvoice" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" ToolTip="Invoice">
        <controls:Tile.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="/Resources/invoice.png"/>
        </controls:Tile.Background>
    </controls:Tile>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Aa thanks. How I could add visible text, which is also resizable.

Comment: What do you mean? Add text where, to your tile?

Comment: If thats the case, Tile has a `Title` property you can set.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this code.

```
<Viewbox Grid.Row="1">
<controls:Tile Name="tileInvoice" Click="tileInvoice_Click" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ToolTip="{x:Static resx:omniLang.Invoice}">
<controls:Tile.Background>
<ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/invoice.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
</controls:Tile.Background>
<TextBlock Name="headerInvoice" Text="{x:Static resx:omniLang.Invoice}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,100,0,0" />
</controls:Tile>
</Viewbox>
```